# Android Call Blocker Code for Android 3.0 and above

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I googled for an example source code for blocking calls and came across this [EXAMPLE](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html), But later I came to know that Google has updated their policy and

```
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
```

is an system level permission from android version 2.3, I have very important module placed on blocking a specific call.
**How do I get a system level permission?**

Please let me know if there is any way I can do this in my application. Its very important for the product and cannot be released without this functionality.

Please Help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope there is no solution for your problem, otherwise this would be a huge security hole in android platform. So you are left with creating your own custom ROM.

Comment: Can you please put some more light on this point "creating your own custom ROM"

Answer (score 0):

At least as of Android 5.0, `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` has the following definition:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
  android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PHONE_CALLS"
  android:protectionLevel="signature|system"
  android:label="@string/permlab_modifyPhoneState"
  android:description="@string/permdesc_modifyPhoneState" />
```

Your app can only hold this permission and use it to modify the phone state if it is signed by the firmware's signing key (the "your own custom ROM" scenario from Marcin's comment) or if your app is installed on the system partition. The latter can be accomplished by having your app pre-installed on the device (or having a rooted device user move your app to the system partition, as I understand it).